Proving TWO-COLORED-HAMILTONIAN-CYCLE is complete
Consider the following problems:
TCHC :=
{
⟨G, c⟩ | G(V, E) is a directed graph with an even number of vertices along with
an edge coloring c and G has a directed Hamiltonian cycle with no
two consecutive edges of the same color
}.
DHC :=
{
⟨G'⟩ | G'(V', E') is a directed graph that has a directed Hamiltonian cycle
}.
Assume that DHC is NP-complete.
I'm trying to reduce DHC to TCHC, but I'm having trouble with the case when DHC is an odd Hamiltonian cycle. I tried adding an extra vertex, but I failed to come up with such an arrangement of edges that all True/False answers from DHC would map to TCHC. I'd highly appreciate any pointers or solutions.

Duplicate each vertex into two.
Formally, given $G = (V, E)$, create $G' = (V', E')$, with:

$V'= \bigcup\limits_{v\in V}\{v_1, v_2\}$;
$E'$ is composed of:

red edges $\{(u_2, v_1) \mid (u, v) \in E\}$;
and blue edges $\{(v_1, v_2)\mid v\in V\}$




Sorry, but I don't see it.
My logic:
We have |V| = n original vertices and we add |E| = m extra vertices. Since the original Hamiltonian cycle had exactly n edges, we need to take care of extra m - n vertices to create a colored Hamiltonian cycle. Hence, we add extra m-n dummy vertices, and therefore we have 2n + 2(m - n) = 2m vertices, so our new graph is always even.
However, I can't see a way of using dummy vertices v_d to visit every v_e not in the cycle without introducing a false positive Hamiltonian cycle. I defined every v_d to have inc red and out blue edge for each v_e

@Alex Yeah, after much thought, I am not sure my first solution would work. I edited my answer.

Thanks, this solution makes sense!
